# How do I disable the Message "Int-arithr A sub-expression may overflow ..."

Tags: visual-c++, diagnostics

I am changing a program from VS2019 x86 to VS2022 x64.  In the VS2019 version I am getting no errors and no warnings and no messages.

In the VS2022 version of this snippet--

```
int     nn;
string  sParse;
```

sParse = sParse.substr( 0, nn ) + sParse( nn + 1 ); // Drop 1 character

```
I am getting a message "Int-arithr A sub-expression may overflow before being assigned to a wider type."  From what little I've gleaned, I think it's coming from code analysis(?).  The "nn" in "nn + 1" has 3 dots under it.

I've googled for information/documentation on this "message" (it's listed with a blue information icon) and can't find any.  While I have used #pragma warning to disable a warning, I have never tried to disable a "message."  What is the message trying to tell me?  How do I suppress the compiler from reporting it?
```

Comment: "Drop 1 character" can be more directly expressed as `sParse.erase(nn, 1)`. Likely better performance, too.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably a good workaround and I will try it. But, what I want to know is what is causing the message and how to disable it.

Comment: Perhaps you could make `nn` of type `size_t` rather than `int`

Comment: There's another workaround maybe.  Again, I'm not looking for how to get around it.  I'm trying to understand what the compiler thinks is going on.  Here's another example of the same diagnostic.

Comment: if ( sParse[[n-1] == '.' ) { ... }  The dots are under again under the n and the suggestion  is to switch to a wider type to avoid overflow,  What's going on?  [Sorry, I'm not sure how to quote code in a comment]

Comment: @IgorTandetnik your suggestion to use sParse.erase produces the same diagnostic as the original statement.

Comment: Since `nn` is `a signed type, I guess the analyzer thinks it could be negative, and then overflow to a large positive value when converted to `size_t`. Position parameters to various string methods are of type `size_t` (an unsigned type, likely 64 bits large on 64-bit build, while `int` is still 32 bit). Hence the advice to make `nn` have type `size_t`, to match the type of the parameter.

Comment: Using size_t helps but does not eliminate the problem.  Changing /W3 to /W2 also helps.  I will continue to try things to get a balance in favor of meaningful messages.